# Definition of Path Connected in Munkres’ Topology

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, proof-writing, definition, path-connected

> Given point $x$ and $y$ of the space $X$, a **path** in $X$ from $x$ to $y$ is a continuous map $f:[a,b]\to X$ of one closed interval in the real line into $X$, such that $f(x)=a$ and $f(y)=b$. A space $X$ is said to be **path connected** if every pair of points of $X$ can be joined by a path in $X$.

Why do you we use $[a,b]$ interval? Isn’t $[0,1]$ interval is more explicit to use? and word “joined” in definition of path connected mean? Is it $\exists$ path from $x$ to $y$ and $\exists$ path from $y$ to $x$?

> Path connected $\implies$ connected

**Approach(1):** Munkres’ proof. By lemma 24.1 corollary, $[0,1]$ is connected. By theorem 23.5, $f([0,1])$ is connected. By lemma 23.2, either $f([0,1])\subseteq A$ or $f([0,1]) \subseteq B$. If $f([0,1]) \subseteq A$, then $f(1)=b\in A$. Which is a contradiction, because $b\in B$. If $f([0,1]) \subseteq B$, then $f(0)=a\in B$. Which is a contradiction, because $a\in A$. Thus $\nexists$ separation of $X$. Hence $X$ is connected.

**Approach(2):** Let $A$ and $B$ form separation of $X$. Since $A,B\neq \emptyset$, $\exists a\in A$ and $\exists b\in B$. Since $X$ is path connected and $a,b\in X$, $\exists f:[0,1]=I \to X$ such that $f$ is continuous, $f(0)=a$ and $f(1)=b$. So $0\in f^{-1}(A)$ and $1\in f^{-1}(B)$. Thus $f^{-1}(A), f^{-1}(B)\neq \emptyset$. $f^{-1} (A)\cap f^{-1}(B)=\emptyset$. $f^{-1} (A)\cup f^{-1}(B)=[0,1]=I$. Since $f$ is continuous, $f^{-1}(A),f^{-1}(B)\in \mathcal{T}_I$. Thus $f^{-1}(A)$ and $f^{-1}(B)$ form separation of $[0,1]$. By lemma 24.1 corollary, $[0,1]$ is connected. Thus we reach contradiction. **Is this proof correct?** In this approach we don’t make use lots of fact that we used in approach(1).

**Approach(3):** https://courses-archive.maths.ox.ac.uk/node/view_material/50743. Direct proof. Proposition 1.89, page number 19.

**Approach(4):** let $f:X \to \{0,1\}$ be a continuous map. We need to show $f$ is constant. Let $x,y\in X$. Since $X$ is path connected, $\exists p:[0,1] \to X$ such that $p$ is continuous and $p(0)=x$ and $p(1)=y$. By theorem 18.2(c), $f \circ p:[0,1]\to \{0,1\}$ is continuous. Since $[0,1]$ is connected, $f\circ p$ is constant by definition of connectedness. So $f\circ p(0)=f(x)=f\circ p(1)=f(y)$. Thus $f(x)=f(y)$, $\forall x,y\in X$. Hence $f$ is constant and $X$ is connected.

Comment: Since $[0,1]$ and $[a,b]$ are homeomorphic, it doesn't matter which you use.

Comment: Both proofs hinge on the fact that $[0,1]$ is itself connected.  There is no essential difference.

Comment: @Randall yeah. They are very similar.

Comment: $a$ and $b$ are joined by a path is another way of saying that there is a path from $a$ to $b$. They’re synonyms.

Comment: Approach 2 is cleaner IMO. We only need continuity of a path and connectedness of $[0,1]$.

Comment: How was lemma 23.2 proven? By showing that if a set intersected both sides of a disconnection, it induces a disconnection of that set, so the set cannot be connected. How was theorem 23.5 proven? By showing that if $A, B$ are a disconnection of the image of a continuous function $f$, then $f^{-1}(A), f^{-1}(B)$ are a disconnection of its domain. Approach (2) merely takes the elements of the proofs of those two results and substitutes for them in Approach (1). Approach (2) and Approach (1) are in fact the same proof.

Comment: ?? I'm just addressing your question, They are effectively the same proof, so yes, Approach (2) is correct. I didn't make any accusations of "magic".

Comment: @PaulSinclair Approach (2) and Approach (1) are in fact the “same” proof. I use word “similar” instead of same. There always be some relation between two proof of a problem. Showing that relation don’t make proof “same”(or identical), IMO.

Comment: (a) There is not always some relation between two proofs of the same thing. For instance $0\cdot 1 = 0$ can be proved either by the multiplicative identity axiom of real numbers, or by the distributive and additive inverse axioms. These proofs come from distinct sets of axioms. (b) If two "proofs" follow the exact same logic chain, but in one, sections of that logic chain have been broken out as separate theorems that are then referenced, then I have to disagree. they remain the same proof. (c) If you understood this relationship already, then what was the point of your question?

Comment: By (c), I mean why would you ask if approach (2) is valid, when you already know it just brings the logic of those two theorems directly into the proof? If the logic didn't work, it wouldn't have worked in either one of the other proofs, or in (1). And why would you worry that it didn't mention the other two theorems if you understood that the logic of  their proofs were included in (2)? the only purpose in referencing other results is not to repeat their logic. But there is nothing wrong with repeating that logic instead.